# Applying mapToGlobal to main window position

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

Here is some code that creates a single window and, just for fun, lets you click in the window to print `self.pos()` and `self.mapToGlobal(self.pos())`:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class WinPosExplore(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QApplication.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create("Plastique"))
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.show()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            winPos=self.pos() 
            globalWinPos = self.mapToGlobal(winPos)  
            msg1="winPos=self.pos(): <{0}, {1}>\n".format(winPos.x(), winPos.y())
            msg2="self.mapToGlobal(winPos): <{0}, {1}>\n\n".format(globalWinPos.x(), globalWinPos.y())
            print msg1 + msg2

def main():
    import sys
    qtApp=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWinPos=WinPosExplore()
    sys.exit(qtApp.exec_())

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Because I only am using a single top-level window, I would expect the two sets of coordinates to be the same. That is, I expect the program to realize that for the parent window of the application, `mapToGlobal` is just the identity function. But this is not what happens. I get different coordinates in ways that are not explicable (by me). For example, the following is one printout:

```
winPos=self.pos(): <86, 101> 
self.mapToGlobal(winPos): <176, 225>
```

Can anyone explain what is happening?

Note, I realize this is a silly exercise to some degree (we don't technically ever need mapToGlobal for the main window, as pointed out at [this post at qtforum](http://www.qtforum.org/article/4482/repositioning-a-window-maptoglobal.html)). But I am still curious if anyone can make sense of this behavior in this corner case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Docs:

> `QPoint QWidget::mapToGlobal ( const QPoint & pos ) const`
>
> Translates the widget coordinate `pos` to global screen coordinates. For
>   example, `mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,0))` would give the global coordinates of
>   the top-left pixel of the widget.

The *input* to `mapToGlobal` is a point in widget coordinates, i.e. it's relative to the top-left of widget area.

To clarify, consider this image from [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/application-windows.html#window-geometry):

[image]

`mapToGlobal(self.pos())` will give you `self.geometry().topLeft() + self.pos()`

*Note*: `mapToGlobal(QPoint(0, 0))` will not give same result as `self.pos()` either. This is because window decorations like title bar, etc. are not included in the widget area (see the difference between `geometry().topLeft()` and `pos()` in the image above).

Comment: So basically if the input itself comes from the main window, you will end up with `self.mapToGlobal(self.pos)==2*self.pos + delta`
where delta is the additional size of title bars and borders and such, because they are not included in the widget area. My mistake was thinking it was more sophisticated than it is: basically it just adds whatever point you feed it (*no matter its origin*) to the location of the main window's top-left origin point. I thought it would have some kind of correction when the point came from the main window itself.

Comment: @neuronet: I'm not sure I agree with your edits. Also I don't know what you mean by 'input point is not appropriate'. I'll edit to make things clearer.

Comment: By 'not appropriate' I mean it is not giving a coordinate relative to the main window. That is, like my case where I gave it the pos() of the main window (using pos() on main window gives screen-relative coordinates, i.e., globalPos).

Comment: @neuronet: it doesn't matter what `.pos()` gives you. It's a `QPoint` at the end and `mapToGlobal` doesn't care/know where that came from. `mapToGlobal` will treat that point as widget-relative position.

Comment: Yes hence in my first comment "it just adds whatever point you feed it (no matter its origin) to the location of the main window's top-left origin point. I thought it would have some kind of correction when the point came from the main window itself." The equation I gave above is very useful for thinking about it...I had considered it, but without the delta, and your final remark in your answer showed me the light to the correct equation.

Comment: @neuronet: I've edited the answer. Hopefully, this is clearer.